# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to create a web application running on Tomcat 7.0 with JRE JavaSE-1.6 on osx 10.8. 
I am using a tutorial from the developers site and the error occurs when I try to call

```
clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(new JacksonFactory(), reader);
```

I added the Jar *google-http-client-jackson-1.16.0-rc.jar* to my build path and still get following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/json/JsonFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory
```

My classpath specifically points to this Jar too.

Comment: check your library dependencies first.
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup

Comment: It seems like all dependency are included though.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you finally solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this by changing the following lines:

Original: `import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;`

Modified: `import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it by manually adding the required JAR's to my WEB-INF\lib folder outside Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

From this page [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/gettingstartedwithjava), it says you need 3 libraries:
1) The Generated Java client library for BigQuery
2) The Google HTTP Client Library for Java
3) The Google OAuth Client Library for Java

Do you have them all? It sounds like you have #2, but it sounds like you're missing the google [HTTP client](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/).

Comment: I have all 3 of them but still doesn't work. I also tried to directly add the Google BigQuery API to my Eclipse project but same problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. In POM add below dependency-

   ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client-gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>1.34.1</version>
    </dependency>
   ```

Note: In above dependency version can be changed

2.Import statement

```
    import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
    import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
```

3. Usage

   ```
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = 
                  GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, 
                    new InputStreamReader(in));
   ```