# Is it possible to do a java cron job in order to export a BigQuery table?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I want to upload a java cron job in order to do some queries and export a table from BigQuery to Google Storage once a week. To do this, I've used the Google plugin for Eclipse for upload the cron to AppEngine.

The problem is that my java cron job calls a java class that has google maven dependencies to access to BigQuery, but when the cron is uploaded to AppEngine, the below error appears:

```
Error for /cron/gaejcronjob 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/json/JsonFactory
```

I've read the question: 
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561496/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-google-api-client-json-jsonfactory), but its response don't solve the problem.

**Edit**:
(added pom.xml, GAEJCronServlet.java and BigQuery.java code)

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>XTG.Cron.Jobs</groupId>
    <artifactId>BigQuery</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

GAEJCronServlet.java:

```
package com.gaejexperiments.cron;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import com.gaejexperiments.cron.BigQuery;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GAEJCronServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger(GAEJCronServlet.class.getName());

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

        try {
            _logger.info("Cron Job has been executed");

            BigQuery bigquery = new BigQuery();

            bigquery.exportTable();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //_logger.info(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(req, resp);
    }
}
```

BigQuery.java:

```
package com.gaejexperiments.cron;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.ErrorProto;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.Job;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.JobConfiguration;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.JobConfigurationExtract;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.JobReference;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableReference;

public class BigQuery {
    private final String PROJECT_ID = projectId;
    private final String DATASET_ID = "bigquerytest";
    private final String TABLE_ID = "test";

    private Bigquery service = null;

    public void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

            GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(httpTransport, jsonFactory);

            Bigquery.Builder serviceBuilder = 
                new Bigquery.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("Bigquery ");

            service = serviceBuilder.build();

            if (service == null || service.jobs() == null) {
                throw new Exception("Service is null");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Caught exception: " + ex + "\n");
            ex.printStackTrace();

            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void exportTable() throws Exception{

        //Export
        TableReference sourceTable = new TableReference();
        sourceTable.setProjectId(PROJECT_ID);
        sourceTable.setDatasetId(DATASET_ID);
        sourceTable.setTableId(TABLE_ID);

        JobConfigurationExtract jobExtract = new JobConfigurationExtract();
        jobExtract.setDestinationFormat("CSV");
        jobExtract.setDestinationUri("gs://xtg-bigquery/test1.csv");
        jobExtract.setSourceTable(sourceTable);

        JobConfiguration jobConfig = new JobConfiguration();
        jobConfig.setExtract(jobExtract);

        JobReference jobRef = new JobReference();
        jobRef.setProjectId(PROJECT_ID);

        Job outputJob = new Job();
        outputJob.setConfiguration(jobConfig);
        outputJob.setJobReference(jobRef);

        Job job = service.jobs().insert(PROJECT_ID, 
                                        outputJob).execute();

        if (job == null) {
            throw new Exception("Job is null");
        }

        while (true) {
            String status = job.getStatus().getState();

            if (status != null || ("DONE").equalsIgnoreCase(status)) {
                break;
            }

            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

        ErrorProto errorResult = job.getStatus().getErrorResult();

        if (errorResult != null) {
            throw new Exception("Error running job: " + errorResult);
        }                   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the contents of your pom.xml and your cron servlet to the question.

Comment: @konqi, the content of those files has been added.

Comment: cron.xml and web.xml are irrelevant for this kind error. The contents of your GAEJCronServlet class are relevant and the whole of your pom.xml.

Comment: @konqi, now you can find the relevant files.

Comment: Hm, i'll have to take a look at the dependency tree of the *google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all* artifact but it looks like you manually added stuff to your classpath which is then not available when you deploy. Try adding `<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.21.0</version>
</dependency>` as dependency for a start.

Comment: Correction: The *google-api-client* is a dependency of *google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all* but it is scoped *compile*, so it is present locally but the dependent jars will not be deployed. Try adding the dependencies manually as mentioned in my former comment.

Comment: I've added the next dependencies: <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId><version>1.21.0</version>, <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId><version>1.21.0</version>, <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId><version>1.21.0</version>, <artifactId>google-api-services-bigquery</artifactId><version>v2-rev254-1.21.0</version> but I got the same error. Should I add the dependent jars to "/war/WEB-INF/lib"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a couple of appengine specific pom settings. The recommended approach is to create the pom.xml from the app engine archetype like this ([as described here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven)):

```
mvn archetype:generate -Dappengine-version=1.9.30 -Dapplication-id=your-app-id -Dfilter=com.google.appengine.archetypes:appengine-skeleton-archetype
```

Alternatively you can add the build plugins into your existing pom.xml, the build section should then look something like this (that's basically what the archetype will create for you):

```
<build>
  <!-- for hot reload of the web application-->
  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <version>3.1</version>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
        <webResources>
          <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
          <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
          </resource>
        </webResources>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${appengine.version}</version>
      <configuration>
        <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
        <version>${app.version}</version>
        <!-- Comment in the below snippet to bind to all IPs instead of just localhost -->
        <address>0.0.0.0</address>
        <port>8080</port>
        <!-- Comment in the below snippet to enable local debugging with a remote debugger
                         like those included with Eclipse or IntelliJ -->
        <jvmFlags>
          <jvmFlag>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n</jvmFlag>
        </jvmFlags>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>gcloud-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${gcloud.plugin.version}</version>
      <configuration>
        <set_default>true</set_default>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

You should also add the appengine sdk to your dependencies, mine usually looks like this:

```
<!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>${appengine.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>jstl</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Last but not least, the packaging of appengine projects is usually set to WAR

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Having setup all that (and having a appengine-web.xml present in WEB-INF) you can deploy your appengine application with

```
mvn appengine:update
```

I recommend you create a project with the archetype and copy your content in the new project. That's much easier than adding all those configurations to your existing project.

Comment: After following your instructions closely, I've been able to upload the cron "without" errors. The problem is that the cron seems that is not able to access to my BigQuery class, and the bigquery operations hasn't been realized.

Comment: @MarcosBarragán Yup, your `main` method in your BigQuery class will not be called. This is Java EE, not Java SE. Rename you `main` method to something like `init`, make it non-static and call `init` before calling `exportTable`. You could move the code from `main` to the class constructor of your `BigQuery` class, but that is unwise. If this gives you any trouble, please start another question. It would be off-topic to discuss this much further in the context of this question.